# Ошибка "TypeError: Too many arguments were passed!"

Tags: telegram, aiogram

Друзья, приветствую. Я новокек в aiograme. Поэтому появилась ошибка... Час мучаюсь с этой ошибкой, не могу решить (

Код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from cgitb import text
from email import message
from lib2to3.pgen2 import token
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import sqlite3
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import BotBlocked
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
import typing
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData

import markup as m


class Vorker_Menu(StatesGroup):
    menuVORKKK = State()


invite_callback = CallbackData("invite", "user_id")
admin_id = айди


token = 'токен'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state=None)
async def start_message(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Как звать?')
    await Vorker_Menu.menuVORKKK.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Vorker_Menu.menuVORKKK)
async def vorker_money3(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    yes_button = InlineKeyboardButton(
        'Принять', callback_data=invite_callback.new(action='yes', user_id=message.from_user.id))
    no_button = InlineKeyboardButton(
        'Отклонить', callback_data=invite_callback.new(action='no'), user_id=message.from_user.id)
    invite_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        row_width=1).row(yes_button, no_button)
    name = message.text
    await bot.send_message(admin_id, f'Его звать: {name}', reply_markup=invite_keyboard)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='yes')
async def callback_vote_action(query: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: typing.Dict[str, str]):
    user_id = callback_data.get("user_id")
    print(f'{user_id}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Чел, бот запустился')
executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Я понимаю, что это полнейший г-код, но я тут изучаю callback_data

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Меняйте это

```
invite_callback = CallbackData("invite", "user_id")

no_button = InlineKeyboardButton(
    'Отклонить', 
    callback_data=invite_callback.new(action='no'), user_id=message.from_user.id)
```

На это

```
invite_callback = CallbackData("invite", "action", "user_id")

no_button = InlineKeyboardButton(
    'Отклонить', 
    callback_data=invite_callback.new(action='no', user_id=message.from_user.id))
```

Comment: не получилось, в cmd пишет, что ошибка тут "'Принять', callback_data=invite_callback.new(action='yes', user_id=message.from_user.id))"

Comment: Обновил, проверяйте